# Repeated values ​when join data frames in r

Tags: r

when I merge dataframes, I write this code:

```
library(readxl)
df1 <- read_excel("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/precipitaciones_4Q.xlsx")
df2 <- read_excel("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/libro_copia_1.xlsx")

df1 = data.frame(df1) 
df2 = data.frame(df2)

df1$codigo = toupper(df1$codigo)
df2$codigo = toupper(df2$codigo)      


dat = merge.data.frame(df1,df2,by= "codigo", all.y =  TRUE,sort = TRUE)
```

the data has rainfall counties, df1 has less counties than df2. I want to paste counties that has rainfall data from df1 to df2. 
The problem occurs when counties data are paste into df2, repeat counties appears.

df1:

[image: df1 image]

df2:

[image: df2 image]

Comment: It's not recommended to read straight from `xlsx`. Do you have example data?

Comment: I modified the publication, I put two  images

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data that people can work with (not pictures of it), all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.

Comment: ok, that´s true. where can I upload data base ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead "id" you must specify the column names for join from the first and second table.
You can use the `data.table` package and code below:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = "Columna1", by.y = "prov", all.y = TRUE)
```

also, you can use `funion` function:

```
dat <- funion(df1, df2)
```

or `rbind` function:

```
dat <- rbind(df1, df2)
dat <- unique(dat)
```

**Note:** column names and the number of columns of the two dataframes needs to be same.

Comment: I get this error:
Error in .set_ops_arg_check(x, y, all, block_list = !all) : 
  x and y must both be data.tables

Comment: You must convert your objects to datatable. To do this, run the following command: `df1 <- as.data.table(name_of_your_first_table)`, `df2 <- as.data.table(name_of_your_second_table)`

Comment: I get a new error : x and y must have the same column classes

Comment: Check which columns have different classes in the two tables. 
This can be done in a RStudio environment. 
Columns, that will have different classes must be reduced to the same class (you can use the `as.type` function to replace the type of an object, for example, `df1$codigo <- as.character(df1$codigo)`)

Comment: In the second table, you don't have a column named `codigo`. You need rename the column `departamento` to `codigo`, or use the method that I indicated above (merge the tables by columns with different names).